# Replace and remove text from string in sql server

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have string like the following, it is sample

```
<b>22/10 - 10:47 - wes:</b> ###TaskDefId=46###N Enq - Send Quote<b><br/>29/10 - 15:55 - grn: Some Text ###TaskDefId=31### ABC - DEFG HIJ<b><br/>22/10 - 12:29 - white: ....
```

Please see below this is the complete string, the original looks like above, I have removed `b` and `br` tags to make it more clearer. At the end of each line I have write down that what I want to remove and what I want to replace.

```
22/10 - 10:47 - wes: ###TaskDefId=46###N Enq - Send Quote               '###TaskDefId=46###N Enq - Send Quote' This should be removed completely 
29/10 - 15:55 - grn: Some Text ###TaskDefId=31### ABC - DEFG HIJ            '###TaskDefId=31###' This should be replaced with 'STAGE CHNAGED:'
22/10 - 12:29 - white: Eamiled ###TaskDefId=31### Qtd - Email and Email     '###TaskDefId=31###Qtd - Email and Email' This should be removed completely because last stage was exactly same
29/10 - 16:26 - wesl: Spoke ###TOaskDefId=48### CTD - DDDDDD            '###TOaskDefId=48###' This should be replaced with 'STAGE CHANGED:' becaue last stage was different
09/12 - 13:12 - wesl: Spoke ###TaskDefId=31### CTD - DDDDDD         '###TaskDefId=31###' This should be replaced with 'STAGE CHANGED:' becaue last stage was different
15/11 - 18:41 - white: Some xxxx ###TaskDefId=31### DDD AND - CDD TDED      '###TaskDefId=31###' This should be removed.
09/12 - 13:12 - wesl: Balanced ###TaskDefId=23### SDTED DERDDW          '###TaskDefId=23###' This should be replaced with 'STAGE CHANGED:'
```

If question looks messy please copy and paste in notepad and I hope the question will make sense. Let me again tell you that this is one string not different rows.

**EDIT:**

1. This string is in one column of
   table and I need to update the same
   column after these changes.
2. As I have explained in my question
   that I don't just want to replace
   and remove the pattern but replace
   the ###TaskDefId=seomnumber### with
   'STAGE CHANGED:' if last occurrence
   of the pattern and the current one
   is exactly same and removed if last
   occurrence of the pattern and the
   current one is different.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us what your table structure looks like?? Most importantly: what **datatype** does this column have that contains this data??

Comment: Thanks @marc_s. DataType is VARCHAR(MAX) and I have this string in one column named NotesHistory and I have to updated same column after these changes

Comment: This seems more fit at an application level (Especially with circumstances like only perform the replace is the previous one is the same). Find a language you're comfortable with and can connect to the database with, extract the data, perform your cleanup, then continue on. If there are a lot of rows, it may be wise to add a "cleaned_up" column so you can batch it off.

Comment: @Brad Christie, thanks for the suggestion and it looks like that this is the solution of this, because no sql guru has come with solution yet.

Comment: @Muhammad: It's not about being a guru--SQL is designed for storage and retrieval, not manipulation. There are "convenient" string functions integrated with SQL, but nothing heavy enough to do this kind of interrogation on the data stored within.

Comment: @Muhammad: As an aside, I would look in to (if this is recurring) breaking those entries off in to a log table. It appears you're keeping contact history, which might be better served in a linked table not raw entries in a TEXT field.

Comment: I agree with Brad - T-SQL is pretty weak when it comes to string manipulation; as soon as you want to do something like regular expressions or something like that, you'll have to resort to C#/VB.NET to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use -

```
SELECT REPLACE ( string_expression , string_pattern , string_replacement )
GO
```

But in your string I see many patterns that you want to replace. I would suggest you can use something like -

```
Declare @String_Original nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @Replacement1 nvarchar(50)
DECLARE @Pattern1 nvarchar(50)

@String_Original = 'your string'
@Pattern1 = '###TaskDefId=31###'
@Replacement1 = 'STAGE CHNAGED:'

SELECT REPLACE(@String_Original,@Pattern1,@Replacement)
```

Now, you will have to do this repeatedly till you have replaced all the patterns that you want to replace.

Perhaps something like -

```
DECLARE @Replacement2 nvarchar(50)
DECLARE @Pattern2 nvarchar(50)

@String_Original = 'your string'
@Pattern2 = '###TaskDefId=46###N Enq - Send Quote'
@Replacement2 = ''

SELECT REPLACE(@String_Original,@Pattern2,@Replacement2)
```

And, do this for all the patterns to be replaced. But, if the pattern to be replaced is dynamic and you dont know it beforehand then I am afraid a simple, straight forward replce will not help you. You will have to write a function or stored procedure with your logic to find the patterns and replace them.

Comment: Thanks @Pavanred but I need to replace or remove ###TaskDefId=somenumber### with respect to the previous occurrence of the pattern. i.e. if previous last occurrence of the pattern is exactly same then remove it otherwise replace it.

Comment: Oh then you will have to write your own logic to find, compare and replace / remove ###TaskDefId=somenumber### from your string. You will be using a lot of PATINDEX, SUBSTRING, REPLACE etc. You have some very dirty string manipulation to do. I would suggest you to find any other solution at a higher level to avoid all this. Leave such string manipulation as your last resort.